# API-only Rails app with 'admin' and 'user' roles best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am rebuilding a standard app in Rails (backend + rendering) and looking into creating API-only Rails backend and Node/React frontent.

I'm a little bit riddled on best practices here.

In my old app I had 2 devise models - User and Admin (admin was a separate namespace, so User would not have access to its controllers).

How would you recommend to implement sets of different controllers for admins and users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always depends in the use case. If the admin has completely other tasks, it's better to create it's own namespace for them. If the admin does the same things as a normal user but with a bit more rights, I would handle the different authorization for both.

For example a user is only authorized to delete his own posts and a admin is allowed to delete all posts.